# WSO2 ESB Secure handler in proxy

Tags: security, oauth, wso2, wso2-esb

I know that I can set up secure API

```
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Securing+APIs
```

but is it possible to set up secure proxy with my own handler?

Answer (score 0):

You can't secure a Proxy service using a Handler as you did in API. But you may consider using OAuth mediator for this purpose. [1] If that does not cater your requirement, you may consider implementing a class mediator .[2][3][4]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/OAuth+Mediator
[2] http://achala11.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-write-custom-mediator-wso2-esb.html
[3] http://wso2.com/library/2898
[4] http://maninda.blogspot.com/2012/11/writing-custom-mediator-for-wso2-esb.html

Comment: Thx for your response. I cannot write my own class mediator, because I have to "extend" two classes and one of it is "AbstractMediator". As I know, in JAVA I cannot do this.